# Could mesuring particles in double slit experiment with gravitational waves work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, gravity, double-slit-experiment, gravitational-waves

From my basic knowledge of quantum physics I know that what makes the double slit experiment hard to understand is the mesurement part. Once you mesure a particle you become part of the wave function so the particle stop acting like a wave.

Theoretically if:

- we could create two very small black hole orbiting around theirself and throw them into the double slit experiment. (Don't know if one black hole is sufficent to mesure gravitational waves, but I don't if sending to particles instead of one could "ruin" the experiment)
- we could mesure gravitational waves of the two spinning black holes

Then nothing is activly interacting with the experiment because we could just mesure the gravitational waves outside the quantum system.

Does it makes sense?

Comment: I am not sure about this question, but I would assume that a theory of quantum gravity would perhaps be needed to accurately predict your scenario.

Comment: @Jonas Do you suggest to edit the question and make it more clear?

Comment: I think the question is clear. My comment was rather intended to be the approach to some sort of answer - my guess it that without a theory of quantum gravity (which we don't have), the outcome cannot be predicted. Please note that this is just a guess; maybe someone else can provide an answer.